# Why does pandas read_excel fail on an openpyxl error saying 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'defined_names'?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

This bug suddenly came up literally today after read_excel previously was working fine.  Fails no matter which version of python3 I use - either 10 or 11.

Do folks know the fix?

```
  File "/Users/aizenman/My Drive/code/daily_new_clients/code/run_daily_housekeeping.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/aizenman/My Drive/code/daily_new_clients/code/run_daily_housekeeping.py", line 25, in main
    sb = diana.superbills.load_superbills_births(args.site, ath)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aizenman/My Drive/code/daily_new_clients/code/diana/superbills.py", line 148, in load_superbills_births
    sb = pd.read_excel(SUPERBILLS_EXCEL, sheet_name="Births", parse_dates=["DOS", "DOB"])
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 482, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1695, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 557, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 545, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 568, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 346, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 303, in read
    self.parser.assign_names()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/workbook.py", line 109, in assign_names
    sheet.defined_names[name] = defn
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'defined_names'
```

Comment: Seems very much related to this issue that was marked as fixed for openpyxl 3.1.1: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1947

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, we face the issue on python3.8 environment (Rocky 8.8 OS). We downgrade the openpyxl module to 3.0.9 to fix this issue.

> sudo pip3 install openpyxl==3.0.9

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 21):

I am using Azure Databricks and I ran into this same issue today. I checked and openpyxl was on version 3.1.1.

At the start of my notebook I added a line to pin to the previous version:

```
%pip install --force-reinstall -v "openpyxl==3.1.0"
```

After that my job was working again. It seems like some change in the most recent update is causing this to break.

Comment: That makes total sense!  I fixed by editing the openpyxl source file directly to say "sheet.defined_names = {}".  Hack-y but got the job done.

Comment: I just pulled in the update to `openpyxl` and I am seeing the same issue.  Someone broke something

Answer (score 1):

You can first try to uninstall the openpyxl
`pip uninstall openpyxl -y`
and then use
`pip install openpyxl==3.1.0 -y`

Note: Use ! infront of code if case of using notebooks.
`!pip uninstall openpyxl -y`
`!pip install openpyxl==3.1.0 -y`

If the above code does not work. You can try to upgrade the pandas. i.e
`!pip uninstall pandas -y` && `!pip install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

By installing the 'xlxswriter', the trouble was solved. Thanks to the above solutions, but they do not work in my case. So, this maybe another issuse you may consider.